# tfs reporting error showing cross mark on reports in tfs 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-reports

I have a problem with rights of TFS2010 reports, 
when i want to open reports in TFS2010, 
it is showing cross mark on reports,
may be i have no rights for reports
what are the rights to access reports?
or what is the problem with reports 
any suggestions????
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need specific rights in SQL Reporting services - the easiest way I know to deal with this is to use http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/

Comment: The team project you are trying to connect to have no SharePoint associated with it. Any missing tier will be disabled from editing and greyed out.

Comment: An error occured when connecting to Reporting Services for the selected team project, to prevent any data corruption you will not be able to administrate this project!

Comment: Can you browse to your report server in a browser? Have you checked both the sql reporting configuration tool and tfs adminstration tool (reporting section) to make sure no errors are being displayed?

Comment: no i cant browse it in my browser it shows an error of credentials!

Comment: what about the 2 admin tools?